# Referencing Multiple (or All) Rows in a join table

Tags: database, join, relational-database

First off, I'm fairly new to database design so I hope my questions makes sense. I'm trying to design a relational database which joins rows in one table to rows in another table. Easy right? Well I'm kind of stumped because there are scenarios in which a row would need to reference every single row in a separate table.

Take the example of beer recipes.

There are a series of ingredient tables (one of them being the *Grain Table*) and a single beer *Styles Table*. The *Grains-Styles Table* is designed to link the *Grains Table* and *Styles Table* to show which grains are appropriate for each beer style.

*Table Grains*

```
id      name                Price
----------------------------------
0       German grain        1.20
1       Regular grain       1.00
2       Wheat               0.90
3       American grain      1.00
```

*Table Styles*

```
id      name                 % Alcohol
--------------------------------------
0       German beer          6
1       Australian beer      4
2       American beer        3
3       Generic Beer         5
```

*Table Grains-Styles*

```
id      style_id             grain_id
-------------------------------------
0       0                    0
1       0                    1
2       0                    2
3       1                    1
```

These are the three scenarios I'm seeing here:

**Scenario 1:** Certain grains are only appropriate for certain beer styles. German grain is only appropriate for german beer.

**Scenario 2:** Certain grain is applicable to all beer styles. Regular grain can be used for  German Beer, American Beer, or any other style.

**Scenario 3:** All grains apply to a specific style. German grain, regular grain, or any other grain can be used in Generic Beer.

It seems to be inefficient to create a ton of rows in the *Grains-Styles Table*. Is there something equivalent to a wildcard value in the style_id AND/OR grain_id columns?

How do I approach this problem? What is this concept called? Just kind of lost here and certainly over my head. Thanks in advance to any help you might be able to provide.

Comment: Small tip: do not use `0` value in primary keys. It is better to leave `0` to mean something exceptional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [Many-to-many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29), and I don't think it is inefficient at all. Since the tuple `(style_id, grain_id)` is unique too, you can use it as primary key and drop the `id` column.

Comment: Well, what if most scenarios are Scenario 2 and 3? If there are 1,000 grains and 1,000 styles isn't that like 1,000,000 rows? Would it be more efficient to store a wildcard as a string and do some kind of logic on the application layer? That seems better to me than write 1,000,000 rows.

Comment: Also, considering there are multiple ingredients (hops, yeasts, various other things) which would function in the same way, this would lead to millions and millions of added rows. Is it "hacky" to add a wildcard string as an id value?

Comment: In that case you are losing normalization, only in order to store less rows. "Tricky" solutions imply adding complexity to and I don't know if it really worths it, since relational DBMS offers other solutions (i.e. why don't use indices instead of denormalizing the database desing?)